# Correct way of setting up Supervisor with Next JS

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, node-supervisor

I am new to Next Js. I have currently installed supervisor to watch for changes in files because nodemon doesn't seem to work well. It works at times and sometimes it doesn't. When it works, I always have to run npm install before running npm run dev.

When it doesn't work, this is what i get

[image]

When it works , after I run npm install

[image]

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "supervisor server.js",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production supervisor server.js",
    "build": "next build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@artsy/fresnel": "^1.2.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.14",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "next": "^10.0.3",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.8",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "nodemailer-sendgrid-transport": "^0.2.0",
    "nookies": "^2.3.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "6.0.0",
    "react-moment": "^0.9.7",
    "react-toastify": "^6.0.5",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "supervisor": "^0.12.0",
    "uuid": "^8.2.0",
    "validator": "^13.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "supervisor": "^0.12.0"
  }
}
```

This is my server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").Server(app);
const next = require("next");
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const nextApp = next({ dev });
const handle = nextApp.getRequestHandler();
require("dotenv").config({ path: "./config.env" });
const connectDb = require("./utilsServer/connectDb");
connectDb();
app.use(express.json());
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

console.log('starting up ++++')
nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
    app.use("/api/signup", require("./api/signup"));
    app.use("/api/auth", require("./api/auth"));
    app.all("*", (req, res) => handle(req, res));

    server.listen(PORT, err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`express app detect changes, Express server running on ${PORT}`);
    });
});
```

Please advise, thank you.
EDIT: I also place an api folder in the root directory , not sure if this has any impact on this issue.